# Run each command until it succeeds, or exit the program if one fails N times

Tags: bash, loops

I have some set of commands and I want to retry max 5 times those command in case of failure.
So I tried to execute those command in loop.

I am doing something like below

```
# execute command1
n=0
until [ $k -ge 5 ]
do
   command1 && break
   sleep 1
   n=$[$n+1]
   if [ "$n" -eq 5 ]; then
    exit 1
   fi
done
# execute command3
k=0
until [ $k -ge 5 ]
do
   command2 && break
   sleep 1
   k=$[$k+1]
   if [ "$k" -eq 5 ]; then
    exit 1
   fi
done
# execute command3
s=0
until [ $s -ge 5 ]
do
   command3 && break
   sleep 1
   s=$[$s+1]
   if [ "$s" -eq 5 ]; then
    exit 1
   fi
done
```

is it possible to execute all 3 commands in a single loop but one condition, each command should execute only 1 time and also in a sequence, means second command should only execute if first completed.

There might be some other approach without using loop. My goal is execute all the commands and in case of failure, it should retry 5 times. I can only use linux preinstalled utility. I can't install any third party command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
for i in {1..5}; { cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && break; }
```

Testing with `ls`:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; { ls && ls && ls && break; }
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
```

All commands executed just once. Now with error:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; { ls && ls && ls not_exist 2>/dev/null && break; }
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
f1  f2  f3  inventory.py  inv_test  ips  list  list2  list3 test  test2
```

Looped 5 times.

Comment: thanks for you answer. each command should work only 1 time. In case, 1 execute successfully but second failed then it  1 command will again execute.